# How to hide all div except the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JQuery and I want to hide all div except the first but the problem is that I display my div (ref_display) by a for loop like that :

```
<div class="col-md-6 ref">
    {% for benefit in benefits %}

    <div class="col-md-6 ref_display">
        <h3>{{ benefit.name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ benefit.description }}</p>
        <div></div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And when I use my JS code, it doesn't work :

```
$(function() {
    var ref = $('div.ref_display');
    ref.gt(0).hide();
});
```

I think JQuery considers that there is only one div when I write `.gt(0)` however, I have many of them displayed on my page..

I'm beginner in JS so there is probably a solution that I don't know :)

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: You can also use `.first()`, eg `ref.hide();ref.first().show();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `gt(0)` is not a function. Presumably you meant `get(0)` but even that has issues as it will return a DOM Element which doesn't have a `hide()` method.

To achieve what you need, you can use the `:gt` selector to get all divs but the first and hide them:

```
$('div.ref_display:gt(0)').hide();
```

That being said you don't need JS/jQuery for this at all as it can be achieved in CSS alone:

```css
div.ref { display: none; }
div.ref:first-child { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 ref">1</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ref">2</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ref">3</div>
```

Comment: this is the best answer among all. Proper explanation with an easier solution.+1

Comment: Yeeeeees thanks you !! I knew it but I don't know why I wanted to use gt() as a function.... I'm stupid sometimes :')

Comment: @Beno No problem, glad to help

Comment: However I knew the css but I have to use JQuery for other things after ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `var ref = $('div.ref_display:gt(0)').hide();`

```js
$(function() {
    $('div.ref_display:gt(0)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 ref">
        
  <div class="col-md-6 ref_display">
    First Div
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ref_display">
    Second Div
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ref_display">
    Third Div
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hide all div except the first

Use `:not(:first-child)`

```
$('div.ref_display:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

Or use `slice`

```
$("'div.ref_display").slice(1).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by simply using **CSS**. `:not(:first-child)` will select all the child elements except the first one

```css
div:not(:first-child) { display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 ref_display">1</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ref_display">2</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ref_display">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not()` as

```
var ref = $('div.ref_display').not(':first').hide();
```

This will ignore the first element with div having class `ref_display`.

Answer (score 0):

Using only css `pseudo selector` `not` & `first-child`

```css
.ref .ref_display:not(:first-child) {
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 ref">
  <div class="col-md-6 ref_display">
    <h3>1</h3>
    <p>1</p>
    <div>X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ref_display">
    <h3>2</h3>
    <p>2</p>
    <div>Y</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ref_display">
    <h3>3</h3>
    <p>3</p>
    <div>Z</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I knew that but I have to use JQuery because I have to do other things after that :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't JS for this at all. Simple CSS should be sufficient `.ref_display + .ref_display`:

> I want to hide all div except the first

But jQuery will work too of course:

```js
$('.ref_display + .ref_display').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 ref_display">#1</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ref_display">#2</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ref_display">#3</div>
```